# ¿Como entro a la configuraciones de mi router desde el terminal mac?

Tags: terminal, redes, router

Necesito entrar a las configuraciones de redes de mi router que son más avanzadas, pero no logro encontrar el comando para terminal mac que me conecte al router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende dle router, algunos utilizan el protocolo Telnet, otros utilizan SSH, si usas telnet puedes instalarlo utilizando brew https://medium.com/ayuth/bring-telnet-back-on-macos-high-sierra-11de98de1544 , si es ssh puedes utilizar el comando nativo de ssh de esta manera: `usuario@ip`.

Recuerda validar que tu router soporte estos tipos de conexiones, para ello puedes hacerlo de tres maneras:

- Leyendo el manual oficial
- Buscando la opción de habilitar acceso shell desde el Dashboard WEB
- Realizando un escaneo de puertos

Si deseas realizar el escaneo de puertos debes utilizar nmap, para ello lo puedes instalar utilizando brew `brew install nmap` y luego ejecutando `nmap -A -T4 ip-rouer`, luego de esto verás los puertos abiertos junto a sus protocolos de conexión, dependiendo del caso será la manera en que puedas administrar tu router.

Comment: en ip-router (ip) lo cambio por la dirección ip del router?

Comment: Esta bien escrito el comando? necesito asignarle algun valor o parametro?

Comment: si, está bien, por ejemplo si la ip es 192.168.1.1 entonces el comando es `telnet 192.168.1.1` o `ssh admin@192.168.1.1`, en el caso de utilizar ssh yo le puse el usuario admin suponiendo que tu router tiene un usuario llamado así, sino lo debes cambiar, en el caso de telnet te solicitará el nombre de usuario y contraseña una ves te conectes al servicio, si no te conecta ni te pide contraseña es porque el router no tiene habilitado el servicio telnet o ssh.

Comment: intento con telnet mas direccion de router

Comment: telnet: connect to address 184.176.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: Tu router no soporta telnet o está deshbailitado, por eso te habia mencionado que primero te asgeures de los servicios que realmente tiene disponible tu router utilizando nmap.